# How to fetch data from multiples tables in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

i am new to hibernate and want to know a few things. I want to implement the following query in hibernate,please guide me.

```
SELECT p.num_is_active
FROM ins.cnfgtr_user_log t, ins.service_user_auth p
WHERE t.source = 'GC'
and t.tokenid = p.txt_auth_token
and t.sessionid = 100000000195756
and t.userid = p.txt_user_id
and t.userid = 'MASTERADMIN'
```

I also want to know do i have to maintain two separate pojo's for these two tables? does this pojo's need to be complete? i mean do they need to contain all the columns of the tables or can they contain only the ones needed for this query?

Comment: In short, Yes. you need to have POJOs for each table if you want to use hibernate. that's the concept of hibernate. POJO to Tables and so on.

Answer (score 0):

**Q:** do i have to maintain two separate POJO's for these two tables?

**Answer:**  Yes you suppose to. Here in ORM each table will be represented by separate POJOs for modularity reasons.

**Q:** does this POJO's need to be complete?

**Answer:** Need not be. Except the columns marked as “not null”. You can use JPA/Hibernate Joins for querying purpose.

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: thanks balaji but to be precise i want to know about the syntax of this query in hibernate. can you help me with it?

Comment: In Hibernate you have option to choose either HQL or our traditional native sql (the same query u posted). First make it work with this query then move to HQL since HQL is quit simple. Ter is another option called criteria which is most OO way of querying.

Comment: Another thing Balaji suppose there are certain tables or views not mapped in Hibernate that we may need to execute a query against, how can this be achieved ?

Comment: If your are using hibernate Query Language (HQL) or Criteria API, all your tables should be mapped otehrwise Hibernate engine does't know other part of the resource and will give you error message. But in case with native SQL you don't need to map anything...  session.createQuery() is for HQL and seesion.createNativeQuery() is for our traditional sql queries where no mappings are required.